# Android Bluetooth LE unplugged device write succeeds (Faster disconnected method?)

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm creating an app which connects to a Bluetooth LE device. Everything works okay, but if a device is unplugged it takes 10-15 seconds for the app to send the STATE_DISCONNECTED broadcast. If I try to write to the device after unplugging it I still see it as a GATT_SUCCESS in my BluetoothGattCallback.

I was going to use if the user tried to change something on the BLE device and its write failed 2-3 times, then show the disconnected screen (or losing connection just so the user had quicker feedback) but that doesn't seem like its going to work. Is there a faster way of checking if the BLE device can no longer be seen?

```
@Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                     int status)
    {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS)
        {
            // Is true even if the device has been unplugged?
            Log.i(TAG, "onCharacteristicWrite Success!");
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "onCharacteristicWrite Failed!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html#PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE? onCharacteristicWrite should really only be called with success status if it got the write response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into similar issue when I was working for a client application. The app would still show that the it is connected to Ble device even after its disconnected for about 10-15 seconds. App wouldn't know that the device is disconnected and it still tries to leave the connection open and it will timeout after some time. Fortunately our Ble device responds after every write from the app. So even though writhecharcetersitc says the write is successfull I will wait the the Ble device tells me that it successfully received my write, which resolved my issue. If its possible for you to change the firmware code I would suggest you to follow the same approach.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, seems like the only approach possible.